# Как преобразовать String в int?

Tags: java

Пробовал преобразовывать вот так, но в чем то ошибка.

```
int num[] = new int[s.length];
for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
{
    num[i] = (Integer)s.charAt(i+1);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Integer.`[`parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))`(String s)`

Comment: Спасибо! А не подскажете как записать строку в массив типа Object? Попробовал по аналогии, но вновь неудача.